# Unable to catch a global exception

Tags: php

Monolog's [StreamHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php) throws a `\UnexpectedValueException` if there's a problem with the specified log file.

In my code I'm trying to catch `\UnexpectedValueException` but I've been not able to.

My code is:

```
<?php
namespace myNamespace;

use Monolog\Logger as Monolog;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;


class Logger {

    private static $instance;

    private static function init()
    {
        if (!self::$instance)
        {
            $logger = new Monolog(MY_LOG_CHANNEL);

            try 
            {                
                $logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(MY_LOG_PATH . "/" . 
                   MY_LOG_NAME, Monolog::NOTICE));            
            }
            catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e)
            {
                writeln("Error starting logger" . $e->getMessage());
                die;
            }

            // and so on
```

It doesn't work, I get this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or
file [somefile.log] could not be opened: failed to open stream: No such file or
directory' in [path to src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php ]
```

As I understand it they have escaped to the global namespace so I should be able to pick it up there. Why can't I? I've tried all combinations of namespace `\myNamesace\UnexpectedValueException` even `Monolog\UnexpectedValueException` global or local, to no avail.

Clearly I'm missing something, what is it please?

**Edit:**

In another class I'm doing an `if (file_exists($fileName)) /** do file_get_contents() etc */ else Logger::error($filename . "does not exist")`

The error is being triggered within `Logger::error()` when I call `self::init()`

The error is caused because I have (purposely) munged the log file path, if it's a valid log file path then the code runs fine. Clearly I want to catch that error, hence the try/catch.

The next line in the trace is the line in the code above: `$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(MY_LOG_PATH . "/" . MY_LOG_NAME, Monolog::NOTICE));`

Interestingly, the only other place I'm catching an exception (this is just scaffolding code at the moment, no business logic yet) is within the `/** do file_get_contents() etc */` bit if I purposely mis-spell the filename var, `file_get_contents` barfs and a standard 
`catch (Exception $e)` works as I'd expect around the `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Why is there a \ before `UnexpectedValueException` in the catch ?

Comment: The error states a log file couldn't be opened, are you sure this error is not thrown by your `writeln` statement?

Comment: @Olivier Because it's trying to catch `UnexpectedValueException`, not `myNamespace\UnexpectedValueException`.

Comment: @Darren What's the complete stack trace, which line does it say the error was thrown in?

Comment: @deceze it's throwing the exception [here](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php#L70) line 70.

Comment: @Darren Go further back in the trace. From where *in your code* was this method invoked?

Comment: Question edited to add clarity.

Comment: @PatrickKostjens No, that's not it. If I comment out `writeln()` it's exactly the same.

Comment: Try catching a simple `Exception`, then use `get_class()` to make sure it's what you expected.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty old question which probably got resolved in the meanwhile. However, for the sake of future visitors, I would like to point out that the exception is thrown when a log entry will be written to the given file, not at construction time.

The way you have the `try { } catch () {}` setup, the exception is expected at the creation of `StreamHandler`. However, the real exception happens whenever you try to send to the log via call like `$logger->error("Error message")` so you should be catching exceptions there.

On another note, I think throwing exceptions from a logging library is one of the silliest things that one could do. Logging should be idempotent and not affect the state of the running application.

Answer (score 0):

In an old silex application, I also ran into this issue. I want to log to a logstash instance, yet it should not break if logstash isn't available.

Luckily, my application used the logger only typed against the `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`, so I could write a decorator preventing the exceptions to break the app at one place, instead of adding a try and catch call on every call within the codebase.

It looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Dreamlines\DirectBookingForm\ServiceProvider;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * DontThrowLoggerDecorator
 *
 * Monolog will break on info, error, etc. calls
 * This decorator wrap the LoggerInterface and ensures that failure to log won't break the app
 **/
class DontThrowLoggerDecorator implements LoggerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }


    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function emergency($message, array $context = array())
    {

        try {
            $this->logger->emergency($message, $context);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function alert($message, array $context = array())
    {
        try {
            $this->logger->alert($message, $context);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function critical($message, array $context = array())
    {
        try {
            $this->logger->critical($message, $context);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function error($message, array $context = array())
    {
        try {
            $this->logger->error($message, $context);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function warning($message, array $context = array())
    {
        try {
            $this->logger->warning($message, $context);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function notice($message, array $context = array())
    {
        try {
            $this->logger->notice($message, $context);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function info($message, array $context = array())
    {
        try {
            $this->logger->info($message, $context);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function debug($message, array $context = array())
    {
        try {
            $this->logger->debug($message, $context);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function log($level, $message, array $context = array())
    {
        try {
            $this->logger->log($level, $message, $context);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }
}
```

and I just wrap my logger instance around this once, in my silex application I am doing it like this:

```
$app['NOT_BREAKING_LOGGER'] = $app->share(
    function () use ($app) {
        return new DontThrowLoggerDecorator($app['monolog']);
    }
);
```

and I am injecting the `NOT_BREAKING_LOGGER` in each of my services instead of the monolog one.